# Complex sound handling (I.E. pitch change while looping)

Tags: android

After going through the lovely set of Java tutorials and a while spent buried in source code I'm beginning to get the feel for it. For my next step, I will dive in with a fully featured application with graphics, sound, sensor use, touch response and a full menu.

My grand idea was to make an animated screwdriver where sliding the controls up and down modulate the frequency and that frequency dictates the sensor data it returns.

Now I have a semi-working sound system but its pretty poor for what its designed to represent and I just wouldn't be happy producing a sub-par end product whether its my first or not.

the problem:

- sound must begin looping when the user presses down on the control
- the sound must stop when the user releases the control
- when moving the control up or down the sound effect must change pitch accordingly
- if the user doesn't remove there finger before backing out of the application it must plate the casing of there device with gold (Easter egg ;P)

now I'm aware of how monolithic the first 3 look and that's why I would really appreciate any help I can get.

sorry for how bad this code looks but my general plan is to create the functional components then refine the code later, no good painting the walls if the roofs not finished.

here's my user input, he set slide stuff is used in the graphics for the control

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    //motion event for the screwdriver view
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
            //make sure the users at least trying to touch the slider
            if (event.getY() > SonicSlideYTop && event.getY() < SonicSlideYBottom)
            {
                //power setup, im using 1.5 to help out the rate on soundpool since it likes 0.5 to 1.5
                SonicPower =  1.5f - ((event.getY() - SonicSlideYTop) / SonicSlideLength);

                //just goes into a method which sets a private variable in my sound pool class thing
                mSonicAudio.setPower(1, SonicPower);

                //this handles the slides graphics
                setSlideY ( (int) event.getY() );


    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    //motion event for the screwdriver view
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
            //make sure the users at least trying to touch the slider
            if (event.getY() > SonicSlideYTop && event.getY() < SonicSlideYBottom)
            {
                //power setup, im using 1.5 to help out the rate on soundpool since it likes 0.5 to 1.5
                SonicPower =  1.5f - ((event.getY() - SonicSlideYTop) / SonicSlideLength);

                //just goes into a method which sets a private variable in my sound pool class thing
                mSonicAudio.setPower(1, SonicPower);

                //this handles the slides graphics
                setSlideY ( (int) event.getY() );

                //this is from my latest attempt at loop pitch change, look for this in my soundPool class
                mSonicAudio.startLoopedSound();
            }
    }


    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {

            if (event.getY() > SonicSlideYTop && event.getY() < SonicSlideYBottom)
            {
                SonicPower =  1.5f - ((event.getY() - SonicSlideYTop) / SonicSlideLength);
                mSonicAudio.setPower(1, SonicPower);
                setSlideY ( (int) event.getY() );
            }
    }


            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                mSonicAudio.stopLoopedSound();
                SonicPower =  1.5f - ((event.getY() - SonicSlideYTop) / SonicSlideLength);
                mSonicAudio.setPower(1, SonicPower);
            }

        return true;

}
```

and here's where those methods end up in my sound pool class its horribly messy but that's because I've been trying a ton of variants to get this to work, you will also notice that I begin to hard code the index, again I was trying to get the methods to work before making them work well.

```
package com.mattster.sonicscrewdriver;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class SoundManager 
{
    private float mPowerLvl = 1f;   
    private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
    private  Context mContext;
    private int streamVolume;
    private int LoopState;
    private long mLastTime;
    public SoundManager()
    {

    }

    public void initSounds(Context theContext) 
    { 
         mContext = theContext;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
         mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
         mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
         streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
    } 

    public void addSound(int index,int SoundID)
    {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(1, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
    }


    public void playUpdate(int index)
    {
        if( LoopState == 1)
        {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now > mLastTime)
            {
                mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, mPowerLvl);     
                mLastTime  = System.currentTimeMillis() + 250;
            }
        }

    }

    public void stopLoopedSound()
    {
        LoopState = 0;
        mSoundPool.setVolume(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), 0, 0);
        mSoundPool.stop(mSoundPoolMap.get(1));
    }
    public void startLoopedSound()
    {
        LoopState = 1;
    }

    public void setPower(int index, float mPower)
    {

        mPowerLvl = mPower;
        mSoundPool.setRate(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), mPowerLvl);
    }

}
```

I almost forgot, that looks pretty ineffective but I omitted my thread which actuality updates it, nothing fancy it just calls:

```
mSonicAudio.playUpdate(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some confusing points in there which I think are just cut and paste issues trying to get the source into this page, but assuming you're not having problems with your onTouchEvent handling, my random comments are:

- It looks like you are calling play() every 250 ms while the touch is held.  I can't see the loop argument to the play() call but I assume it is -1.  If so, then you are launching a brand new looped sound every 250 msc (play returns a unique streamId for every audio stream you create).
- I think you wanted to modify the pitch and amplitude of a single existing stream.  So I think you wanted something like this:

```
int mySoundStreamId = 0;

...

onDown()
   if( mySoundStreamId == 0 ) {
     // create the one true stream
     mySoundStreamId = mySOundPool.play( initial power and freq modifiers, loop = -1 )
   } else {
     // resume the one true stream
     mySoundPool.resume( mySoundStreamId );  // note: a STREAM id is NOT a SOUND id.
   }

onUp()
   if( mySoundStreamId != 0 ) {
      // pause the one true stream
      mySoundPool.pause( mySoundStreamId )  // stop() will release all the samples you held
   }


onWiggle()
   if( mySoundStreamId != 0 ) {
      // modify parameters of the one true stream
      mySoundPool.setPitch( mySoundStreamId, newPitch );  // too lazy to look up real soundPool command
   }

onGameOver
    if( mySoundStreamId != 0 ) {
      // shut down and release the samples of the one true stream
      mySoundPool.setLoop( mySountStreamId, 0 ); // otherwise some phones will keep looping after shutdown
      mySoundPool.stop( mySoundStreamId );  // no resume possible after this, need to reload samples
      mySOundStreamId = 0;
    }
```

I omit the creation/destruction of the sound pool itself.  It sounds like you were successfully loading the sound data into the sound pool ok.

Note that the LOAD returns a SOUND ID which you pass to the PLAY command
but that PLAY returns a STREAM ID which you use in most of the other soundPool methods

---

Of course, I have my own problems with 'resume' on a looped sound, so take what I say with a grain of salt :-)

Good Luck!  I guess I should have checked the time stamp.  My apologies if you posted thie 3 years ago :-)